# A primary key that it is composed of three foreign keys with Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, composite-primary-key

I have a class that represents a DB TABLE, this table has to have a primary key that must be a composition of three foreign keys. How could I do this with Spring boot?

You can find below the code for the classes. The table in question is InfoLocal. It is the one that must have a primary key composed of (the id of the table Local, the id of the table Annee, and the id of the table CodeLocal) which are foreign keys.

[ Please note that @IdClass and @EmbeddedId annotations don't respond to my use case ]

```
@Entity
public class InfoLocal {
    private int nombreDeLocaux;
    private int capaciteUnitaire;
    @ManyToOne
    private Local local;
    @ManyToOne
    private Annee annee;
    @ManyToOne
    private CodeLocal codeLocal;
/* ......*/

}


@Entity
public class Local {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String libelleArabe;
    private String libelleFrancais;
    private int codePatrimoine;
    @ManyToOne
    private Etablissement etablissement;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "local")
    private Collection<InfoLocal> infoLocals;

/* ......*/

}


@Entity
public class CodeLocal {
    @Id
    private int code;
    private String libelleArabe;
    private String libelleFrancais;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "codeLocal")
    private Collection<InfoLocal> infoLocal;
    @ManyToOne
    private TypeLocal typeLocal;

/* ......*/

}

@Entity
public class Annee {
    @Id
    private int codeAnnee;
    private String intitule;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "annee")
    private Collection<InfoLocal> infoLocal;
/* ......*/

}
```

Comment: This really looks like a usecase for  '@IdClass or '@EmbeddedId, eg https://jpa-buddy.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-on-composite-ids-in-jpa-entities/. Can you elaborate on why this is not  a usecase for  '@IdClass or '@EmbeddedId